# Ionic build production shows html errors

Tags: angular8, capacitor, ionic5

I am facing issue while generating production build using ionic. I am using ionic 5 with capacitor 2.2.0
Below is the screenshot of the errors. I am able to do development build(**ionic build**) successfully, but facing issues with **ionic build --prod**

[image]

Above are the html errors which are not observed when executing **ionic build**, but observed when we execute **ionic build --prod**.

As I know production build reduces the file size, but I am not able to understand what is causing the html errors as per the above screenshot.
Is it a problem with angular devkit? Also, I am using angular version 8.

Answer (score 0):

It's intended
With prod it will build with types check in html
If you set the `networkAvailable` to public it should work

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but also i am getting error for ngx translations "Property 'params' does not exist on type 'AppComponent" for {{"messages.no_connection_button" | translate:params}}. Above screenshot also has this issue. please guide me.

Comment: Sry I overlooked that. Looks like the `params` is not defined in your AppComponent or its private too.
If you don't need any variables for you translation string you can just remove `:params` and it should work. 
If you need them make sure that the object exists. 
You can test it with: `... | translate: { fieldName: 3000 }` then you can excess the '3000' in your translation file with `{{fieldName}}`